# Conditional axis label weight in vega-lite (labelFontWeight)

Tags: json, visualization, vega-lite

I have tried many different config in vega-lite but I can't seem to get this to work.
Any help from the community would be appreciated.

Correct result would be only Project 1 to be bold since that record has phase = "0"
I have tried to set "phase" as both string and number.

Thanks

```
"labelFontWeight": {"condition": {"test": {"field": "datum.phase","equal": "0"},"value": "bold"},"value": "normal"}
```

[image]

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "width": 500,
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {
        "phase": "0",
        "name": "Project 1",
        "start": "2023-03-01",
        "end": "2023-03-15",
        "pay": "2023-04-15",
        "status": "On track",
        "description": "This is the description of project 1."
      },
      {
        "phase": "1",
        "name": "Project 2",
        "start": "2023-03-10",
        "end": "2023-04-15",
        "pay": "2023-05-15",
        "status": "Delayed",
        "description": "This is the description of project 2."
      },
      {
        "phase": "2",
        "name": "Project 3",
        "start": "2023-04-01",
        "end": "2023-05-15",
        "pay": "2023-06-15",
        "status": "Behind schedule",
        "description": "This is the description of project 3."
      }
    ]
  },
  "transform": [
    {"calculate": "toDate(utcFormat(now(), '%Y-%m-%d'))", "as": "currentDate"}
  ],
  "title": {
    "text": "Gantt Chart with Rule Line for Today's Date",
    "fontSize": 14,
    "anchor": "start",
    "dy": -15,
    "color": "#706D6C"
  },
  "layer": [
    {
      "mark": {
        "type": "bar",
        "tooltip": true,
        "cornerRadiusTopRight": 4,
        "cornerRadiusBottomRight": 4
      },
      "encoding": {
        "y": {
          "field": "name",
          "type": "nominal",
          "axis": {
            "domain": true,
            "grid": false,
            "ticks": false,
            "labels": true,
            "labelFontSize": 14,
            "labelPadding": 10,
            "labelFontWeight": {"condition": {"test": {"field": "datum.phase","equal": "0"},"value": "bold"},"value": "normal"}
            },
          "title": null
        },
        "x": {
          "field": "start",
          "type": "temporal",
          "timeUnit": "yearmonthdate",
          "axis": {
            "format": "%d-%b",
            "domain": true,
            "grid": false,
            "ticks": true,
            "labels": true,
            "labelFontSize": 11,
            "labelPadding": 6
          },
          "title": null
        },
        "x2": {"field": "end"},
        "color": {
          "title": null,
          "field": "status",
          "type": "nominal",
          "legend": {
            "padding": 0,
            "labelFontSize": 11,
            "labelColor": "#706D6C",
            "rowPadding": 8,
            "symbolOpacity": 0.9,
            "symbolType": "square"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "mark": {"type": "rule", "strokeDash": [2, 2], "strokeWidth": 2},
      "encoding": {
        "x": {
          "field": "currentDate",
          "type": "temporal",
          "axis": {"format": "%d-%b"}
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "mark": {"type": "tick", "thickness": 1, "bandSize": 2, "color": "gray"},
      "encoding": {
        "x": {"field": "pay", "type": "temporal", "axis": {"format": "%d-%b"}},
        "y": {
          "field": "name",
          "type": "nominal",
          "title": null
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "mark": {
        "type": "text",
        "align": "right",
        "baseline": "middle",
        "dx": -5
      },
      "encoding": {
        "x": {"field": "pay", "type": "temporal"},
        "y": {"field": "name", "type": "nominal"},
        "text": {"field": "pay", "type": "temporal", "format": "%d-%b"},
        "color": {"value": "gray"}
      }
    }
  ],
  "config": {"view": {"stroke": null}}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go.

[image]

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "width": 500,
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {
        "phase": "0",
        "name": "Project 1",
        "start": "2023-03-01",
        "end": "2023-03-15",
        "pay": "2023-04-15",
        "status": "On track",
        "description": "This is the description of project 1."
      },
      {
        "phase": "1",
        "name": "Project 2",
        "start": "2023-03-10",
        "end": "2023-04-15",
        "pay": "2023-05-15",
        "status": "Delayed",
        "description": "This is the description of project 2."
      },
      {
        "phase": "2",
        "name": "Project 3",
        "start": "2023-04-01",
        "end": "2023-05-15",
        "pay": "2023-06-15",
        "status": "Behind schedule",
        "description": "This is the description of project 3."
      }
    ]
  },
  "transform": [
    {"calculate": "toDate(utcFormat(now(), '%Y-%m-%d'))", "as": "currentDate"}
  ],
  "title": {
    "text": "Gantt Chart with Rule Line for Today's Date",
    "fontSize": 14,
    "anchor": "start",
    "dy": -15,
    "color": "#706D6C"
  },
  "layer": [
    {
      "mark": {
        "type": "bar",
        "tooltip": true,
        "cornerRadiusTopRight": 4,
        "cornerRadiusBottomRight": 4
      },
      "encoding": {
        "y": {
          "field": "name",
          "type": "nominal",
          "axis": {
            "domain": true,
            "grid": false,
            "ticks": false,
            "labels": true,
            "labelFontSize": 14,
            "labelPadding": 10,
            "labelFontWeight": {
              "expr": "datum.label == 'Project 1'?'bold':'normal'"
            }
          },
          "title": null
        },
        "x": {
          "field": "start",
          "type": "temporal",
          "timeUnit": "yearmonthdate",
          "axis": {
            "format": "%d-%b",
            "domain": true,
            "grid": false,
            "ticks": true,
            "labels": true,
            "labelFontSize": 11,
            "labelPadding": 6
          },
          "title": null
        },
        "x2": {"field": "end"},
        "color": {
          "title": null,
          "field": "status",
          "type": "nominal",
          "legend": {
            "padding": 0,
            "labelFontSize": 11,
            "labelColor": "#706D6C",
            "rowPadding": 8,
            "symbolOpacity": 0.9,
            "symbolType": "square"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "mark": {"type": "rule", "strokeDash": [2, 2], "strokeWidth": 2},
      "encoding": {
        "x": {
          "field": "currentDate",
          "type": "temporal",
          "axis": {"format": "%d-%b"}
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "mark": {"type": "tick", "thickness": 1, "bandSize": 2, "color": "gray"},
      "encoding": {
        "x": {"field": "pay", "type": "temporal", "axis": {"format": "%d-%b"}},
        "y": {"field": "name", "type": "nominal", "title": null}
      }
    },
    {
      "mark": {
        "type": "text",
        "align": "right",
        "baseline": "middle",
        "dx": -5
      },
      "encoding": {
        "x": {"field": "pay", "type": "temporal"},
        "y": {"field": "name", "type": "nominal"},
        "text": {"field": "pay", "type": "temporal", "format": "%d-%b"},
        "color": {"value": "gray"}
      }
    }
  ],
  "config": {"view": {"stroke": null}}
}
```

Comment: Why can't I reference another field? 
In my actual chart I can't hard-code the color and weight based on the label because it needs to be dynamic based on another field.

Comment: As far as I know, axis only has access to the values displayed on the axis itself. If you want to include logic based on other data in your dataset, you need a different approach.

Comment: The only attributes in datum in an axis are datum.label and datum.value as far as I'm aware.

Comment: I have just registered a case on Github. Thanks for replying so quickly.

Comment: Then I can just add some key text to the front of my descriptions and search for those then (using indexof):

"labelFontWeight": {"expr": "indexof(datum.label, '1') !== -1 ?'bold':'normal'"},
"labelColor": {"expr": "indexof(datum.label, '1') !== -1 ? 'black':'gray'"}

Comment: I'm glad to have stumbled across these comments, absolutely perfect solution to a difficult conundrum.

Answer (score 3):

I discovered a more flexible solution for this question.

Just create a new calculate transform where you can connect as many fields as you like to the label.
For example here I connect name, start date and task to a new label: **project_full_descr**

```
"transform": [
{"calculate": "datum.name + ' | Start:' + utcFormat(datum.start,'%B %d, %Y') + ' | Task:' + format(datum.task, '.0f')", "as": "project_full_descr"}
  ],
```

Then in the axis setup we can check if the label contains specific data.
Here I am searching for **Task:0** and setting it to Bold and Black.

```
"labelFontWeight": {"expr": "indexof(datum.label, 'Task:0') !== -1 ?'bold':'normal'"}, 
"labelColor": {"expr": "indexof(datum.label, 'Task:0') !== -1 ? 'black':'gray'"},
```

Now we can also add an expression to clean up the Label description by just selecting text before the first | pipe character.

```
"labelExpr": "split(datum.label, '|')[0]"
```

Entire solution you can use on vega editor:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "width": 500,
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {
        "task": 0,
        "name": "Project 1",
        "start": "2023-03-01",
        "end": "2023-03-15",
        "pay": "2023-04-15",
        "status": "On track",
        "description": "This is the description of project 1."
      },
      {
        "task": 1,
        "name": "Project 2",
        "start": "2023-03-10",
        "end": "2023-04-15",
        "pay": "2023-05-15",
        "status": "Delayed",
        "description": "This is the description of project 2."
      },
      {
        "task": 2,
        "name": "Project 3",
        "start": "2023-04-01",
        "end": "2023-05-15",
        "pay": "2023-06-15",
        "status": "Behind schedule",
        "description": "This is the description of project 3."
      }
    ]
  },
  "transform": [
    {"calculate": "toDate(utcFormat(now(), '%Y-%m-%d'))", "as": "currentDate"},
    {"calculate": "datum.name + ' | Start:' + utcFormat(datum.start,'%B %d, %Y') + ' | Task:' + format(datum.task, '.0f')", "as": "project_full_descr"}
  ],
  "title": {
    "text": "Gantt Chart with Rule Line for Today's Date",
    "fontSize": 14,
    "anchor": "start",
    "dy": -15,
    "color": "#706D6C"
  },
  "layer": [
    {
      "mark": {
        "type": "bar",
        "tooltip": true,
        "cornerRadiusTopRight": 4,
        "cornerRadiusBottomRight": 4
      },
      "encoding": {
        "y": {
          "field": "project_full_descr",
          "type": "nominal",
          "axis": {
            "domain": true,
            "grid": false,
            "ticks": false,
            "labels": true,
            "labelLimit": 800,
            "labelFontSize": 14,
            "labelPadding": 10,
            "labelFontWeight": {"expr": "indexof(datum.label, 'Task:0') !== -1 ?'bold':'normal'"}, 
            "labelColor": {"expr": "indexof(datum.label, 'Task:0') !== -1 ? 'black':'gray'"},
            "labelExpr": "split(datum.label, '|')[0]"
          },
          "title": null
        },
        "x": {
          "field": "start",
          "type": "temporal",
          "timeUnit": "yearmonthdate",
          "axis": {
            "format": "%d-%b",
            "domain": true,
            "grid": false,
            "ticks": true,
            "labels": true,
            "labelFontSize": 11,
            "labelPadding": 6
          },
          "title": null
        },
        "x2": {"field": "end"},
        "color": {
          "title": null,
          "field": "status",
          "type": "nominal",
          "legend": {
            "padding": 0,
            "labelFontSize": 11,
            "labelColor": "#706D6C",
            "rowPadding": 8,
            "symbolOpacity": 0.9,
            "symbolType": "square"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "mark": {"type": "rule", "strokeDash": [2, 2], "strokeWidth": 2},
      "encoding": {
        "x": {
          "field": "currentDate",
          "type": "temporal",
          "axis": {"format": "%d-%b"}
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "mark": {"type": "tick", "thickness": 1, "bandSize": 2, "color": "gray"},
      "encoding": {
        "x": {"field": "pay", "type": "temporal", "axis": {"format": "%d-%b"}},
        "y": {"field": "project_full_descr", "type": "nominal", "title": null}
      }
    },
    {
      "mark": {
        "type": "text",
        "align": "right",
        "baseline": "middle",
        "dx": -5
      },
      "encoding": {
        "x": {"field": "pay", "type": "temporal"},
        "y": {"field": "project_full_descr", "type": "nominal"},
        "text": {"field": "pay", "type": "temporal", "format": "%d-%b"},
        "color": {"value": "gray"}
      }
    }
  ],
  "config": {"view": {"stroke": null}}
}
```

I hope this helpful for the community.